# how do i make a black background for a div with 50% transparency? alpha channel in rgba not working with black

Tags: css, reactjs

alpha channel in rgba specifies the opacity for a color. It works when i use it with other colors, but with black, instead of changing the opacity, it is just making the black color lighter. How do i make it transparent?

background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);

Comment: A black with opacity will show the white underneath thus appearing lighter. It's not clear what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't got a problem.

Try this simple snippet - the background has been set to a color other than white and you can see it mixing with the semi opaque black.

[image]

```css
body {
  background-color: magenta;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

div {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 500%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div></div>
</body>
```

It may be that you are expecting a different sort of black (gray)??